# Importing Google Font into HTML Service

Tags: html, css, google-apps-script, google-font-api

Are you able to import Google Font into Google Apps Script's HTML Service?

I am trying to do:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

And use

```
.nav-stacked li a {
   color: rgb(136, 136, 136);
   display: list-item;
   font: 18px 'Roboto', sans-serif;
   font-weight: 100;
   height: 20px;
   line-height: 20px;
   padding-right: 10px;
   text-indent: 24px;
   width: 194px;
}
```

But it keeps reverting to the sans-serif font.

Thanks for the help,

Answer (score 1):

You need to style it properly

```
.nav-stacked li a {
      font: 18px 'Roboto',sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: It's still not importing correctly. Have you had much luck with importing Google Fonts into the HTML Service?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I found the Caja issue tracker which someone has requested this a feature. It has yet to be responded to.

https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/issues/detail?id=1559&q=google%20font&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary

Please let me know if you found/did something different.